# how to build multiple react applications at heroku using post build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, build, post-build-event

I want to run heroku postbuild for 2 react apps which uses 1 single nodejs server.

This is how I am currently building 1 react app which works perfectly fine

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "shop-user": "npm start --prefix shop-user",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run shop-user\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd shop-user && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
}
```

and my try of doing for 2 apps

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "shop-user": "npm start --prefix shop-user",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run shop-user\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd shop-user && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build && cd .. end-user && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
```

which is not working .

my server.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    app.use('/shop', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'shop-user/build')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'end-user/build')));

    app.get('/shop/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'shop-user/build', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'end-user/build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share what is the error that you are having?

Comment: when i go to https://myurl.herokuapp.com i get page not found 
where I should get  index page for end-user app.

and when I go  https://myurl.herokuapp.com/shop It works perfectly fine .

This is because i guess  because its not building the end-user app

Comment: That page tells you to go to heroku cli and run `heroku logs --tail` to see the logs. You will find what is wrong there. Will be easier to fix it if you know exactly what is the problem.

Comment: noo. it dosent shows heroku logs --tail.
simple **not found**  text and blank page

Comment: I'll check the logs..
bt is this bethod correct ?
of how I am building postbuild script ?

Comment: Ah I thought you are getting a broken app not a 404. Sorry for that I added an Answer that could be the solution.

Comment: the log is showing this error : `error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/end-user/build/index.html'`

Comment: is this a formatting error are you actually missing a `/` here: `cd .. end-user && npm install &&`? after `..`

Comment: soo I have to add `cd ../` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217190/discussion-between-vrecer-and-sagar-chavan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your command for moving to the other repository is broken because you are missing a `/` in your cd command.

replace:
`cd .. end-user && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"`

with:
`cd ../end-user && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"`

That will build your other project.